# Verb for transforming a sphere into a plane

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm designing tools for a 3D modeling software. I've programmed two tools – one which turns a cylinder into a straight plane (and back), and another one which turns a sphere into a plane and *vice versa*. Now I need to know how to call those tools.

The act of transforming a cylinder into a plane can be called *unwrapping* or *unrolling*.

> » Click to unwrap the cylinder «

​

*But is there any verb to describe the transformation from a sphere into a plane?*

> » Click to (?) the sphere «

Comment: Does the sphere turn into a circle or does it cut it kinda like what you would do to turn a globe into a map?

Comment: @Hank – I actually convert the Cartesian coords to spherical and then map them back to X,Y,Z – so it becomes a sphere.

Comment: Whatever – I mean it becomes a **square**.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know, you are either dealing with Euclidean geometry or topology, but not both at the same time.

Comment: http://math.rice.edu/~pcmi/sphere/sphere.html Can't be done. See the diagram. A plane and a circle, can miss each other OR: First they can meet in a single point. In this case the plane is tangent to the sphere at the point of intersection. In the other case the sphere and the plane meet in a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math, a surface that can be transformed into a plane is called a [developable surface.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Developable+surface)  Without stretching it, a sphere cannot be directly developed. Same for a [saddle curve or a torus (donut shape)](https://services.math.duke.edu/education/ccp/materials/mvcalc/parasurfs/para1.html) .

So, **» Click to *develop* the sphere «**

> (Math.)    a surface described by a moving right line, and such that consecutive positions of the generator intersect each other. Hence, the surface can be developed into a plane.

Image of a saddle curve
[image]

Reversing the transformation? How about **back-developing**, **globalizing** (deliberate humor), **rounding out**, and **orbating** or **sphering** (neologisms)?

Comment: Cool! Any ideas how the opposite could be called? (Transforming the plane back to the sphere.) But both 'undevelop' and 'round off' seems fine...

Comment: Right. You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear. How can a three-dimensional sphere (topological figure) be transformed into a two-dimensional surface (Euclidean plane)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lambie You are missing something. The surface of the sphere can also considered to be a [manifold with only 2 dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry)

Comment: Hmm. Well, then, the verb is continuously deform, is it not? You just pull it into a sphere since the two are topologically equivalent. Or am I wrong, based on what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Cartographers and mathematicians have a word for mapping a sphere onto a plane: *projection*.

From [Radical Cartography](http://www.radicalcartography.net/index.html?projectionref):

> Only those projections shown with diagrams are based on simple geometric constructions.

Wikipedia's entry on [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) has some useful diagrams and equations, including: [image: Mercator projection]

The image shows the sphere and the cylinder, as well as the cylinder unrolled.

The verb form of *projection* is *to project.*